# LINQ Query - Object Attributes compare with value in entire datatable

Tags: datatable, linq-to-objects

I have a linq query defined as below.. 'Attributes' (cust.Attributes) is key/value pair.. how can I include this in query (cust.Attributes["Name"] exists in datatable)?

```
            var demo = from obj in employeeObjects
                     let emp = obj as Employee
                     where emp != null && cust.Attributes == DataTable 
                     select emp;
```

Thanks

Comment: How do your datatable looks like? Attributes is a key/value pair of what types? Do you want to check presence of the KEY or VALUE in the datatable?

Comment: If DataTable is a standard System.Data.DataTable, you could make a separate method that takes a value to lookup and which columns to look in in the DataTable, and then use that method in your demo query.  You could also create a query on DataTable to select all of the values from a given column and then do a LINQ intersect between the two queries.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399392.aspx